# Image Editor UI : multi-byte character can not be reflected with Text in Android 7

Tags: android, adobecreativesdk

I can't use Japanese in one of Image Editor UI Tools "Text" on Android 7. 
In editor preview screen provided by Image Editor UI SDK, all Japanese character is reflected on the preview image correctly, but not reflected on saved image and only single-byte character part is reflected.

Anyone have same problem?
Could you please tell me how to solve.
I can't release my APP without fix this issue.

**Reproducibility**

- This issue can be reproduced on Nexus5X Android 7.1
- Not reproduced on Android 4-6.
- no problem at all with aviary-sdk (com.aviary.android.feather.sdk:aviary-sdk:3.X.X)

**Code**

Details:

```
compileSdkVersion 24
buildToolsVersion '24.0.3'
targetSdkVersion 23
minifyEnabled = true
shrinkResources true
compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.0'
compile 'com.adobe.creativesdk.foundation:auth:0.9.1251'
compile 'com.adobe.creativesdk:image:4.8.4'
```

--

```
ToolsFactory.Tools[] tools = new ToolsFactory.Tools[]{
            ToolsFactory.Tools.EFFECTS,
            ToolsFactory.Tools.SHARPNESS,
            ToolsFactory.Tools.LIGHTING,
            ToolsFactory.Tools.REDEYE,
            ToolsFactory.Tools.CROP,
            ToolsFactory.Tools.TEXT,
            ToolsFactory.Tools.WHITEN,
            ToolsFactory.Tools.DRAW,
            ToolsFactory.Tools.BLEMISH,
            ToolsFactory.Tools.MEME,
            ToolsFactory.Tools.ORIENTATION,
            ToolsFactory.Tools.ENHANCE,
            ToolsFactory.Tools.SPLASH,
            ToolsFactory.Tools.FOCUS,
            ToolsFactory.Tools.BLUR,
            ToolsFactory.Tools.VIGNETTE,
            ToolsFactory.Tools.COLOR,
    };

Intent imageEditorIntent = new AdobeImageIntent.Builder(getActivity())
            .setData(uri)
            .withOutputFormat(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG)
            .withOutputQuality(100)
            .withToolList(tools)
            .saveWithNoChanges(true)
            .build();
```